# find() element based on id starting with... and css property

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I select a descendant of an element based on:

- its `id` **starting** with: foo; and
- its css `visibility` set to visible?

`$('#parentEle')find('id^=foo:visible').css({...});` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to use attribute filter(`[]`) for the id attribute, also the :visible filter looks for the display style and height=0

```
$('#parentEle').find('[id^="foo"]').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('visibility') == 'visible'
}).css({});
```

Comment: @user3024007 in that case it is `display` style that is set not visibility